# R: How to remove bad data (characters, numerical, etc.) from matrix

Tags: r, subset

my watered down data set looks like this:

```
ID   name    code  colour   notes
1     sarah  3l1te  0       likes cake
2     jack   3030   1       likes pc
3     $3e    3211   0       likes mac
```

I want this (remove bad input from a column -- numbers and/or characters):

**name column (remove non-number and/or non-string):**

```
ID   name     code  colour notes
1     sarah  3l1te  0    likes cake
2     jack   3030   1    likes pc
3            3211   0    likes mac
```

**code column (remove numbers)**

```
ID   name   code colour notes
1     sarah  3l1te       0    likes cake
2     jack               1    likes pc
3     $3e                0    likes mac

^ Above: how do i remove strings also  ^
```

**Please note that I do not know what the bad input is, I just know it exists :)**

my attempts of removing bad data:

```
data_remove <- subset(data, !is.na(name) & is.numeric(name))
```

later on:

```
data_remove_name <- data_remove$name
```

Attempt 2:

```
data_remove <- subset(data, !is.na(name))
 data_remove_2 <- data_remove[is.numeric(name)]
```

later on:

```
data_remove_name <- data_remove$name
```

Updates:

Bad data = any kind of data that should not be there.

I know what the column should contain (e.g. strings numeric values etc.)

Comment: Is there some sort of rule for what constitutes "bad data"?

Comment: anything that is there when it is not supposed to be. e.g. anything but a number in a number column

Comment: That's not much help when it comes to the character columns. You need quantifiable criteria.  For number columns, use `if ( !(is.numeric(yourdata))) {do_something}`

Comment: @user3609325 That's not a workable definition. How do we know which columns are "number" columns? Every data set is different.

Comment: i know what the input should be in each column. e.g. if it should contain a string or number. if it's a string column, then it can contain any string

Comment: @user3609325 But "$3e" is "any string". If you know the type for each column, then add that to your example. But your question is a bit ridiculous. If there was a way to detect "bad data" in general, everyone would automatically do it. In most cases 60% of data analysis is data cleaning. It's not a simple task because every data set has it's own unique quirks.

Comment: i call that bad data because it's not fully a number or a full string. this option is the least important i just though of it as another possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's (not the most efficient) way to do this

```
data <- read.table(text = "
ID   name    code  colour   notes
1     sarah  3l1te  0       likes_cake
2     jack   3030   1       likes_pc
3     $3e    3211   0       likes_mac", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) # Your data

str(data)
##'data.frame': 3 obs. of  5 variables:
## $ ID    : int  1 2 3
## $ name  : chr  "sarah" "jack" "$3e"
## $ code  : chr  "3l1te" "3030" "3211"
## $ colour: int  0 1 0
## $ notes : chr  "likes_cake" "likes_pc" "likes_mac"

suppressWarnings(data[!is.na(as.numeric(data$code)), "code"] <- "")
suppressWarnings(data[!is.na(sapply(sapply(sapply(data$name, strsplit, ""), as.numeric), any)), "name"] <- "") # couldn't think of a good  way to use `by` here
data

##   ID  name  code colour      notes
## 1  1 sarah 3l1te      0 likes_cake
## 2  2  jack            1   likes_pc
## 3  3                  0  likes_mac
```